Jenkins only Job configuration UI is messed up
Latestly I upgraded the Jenkins to v2.442, everything was working fine but when i check a jobs configuration page the UI is all messed up. Alignmets everythings are messed up.
Can anyone help me resolving the issue?Messed up UI
updated the pluging and restarted the jenkins server

From which version did you upgrade? Is this the case even if you create a new job?

i have upgarded from 2.249 to 2.442. yes if i try to create a new job the same messed UI is showing.

Could be an incompatible plugin. Is the plugins that are in use in the configuration page updated as well??
